# Safety concerns (Cyanide): Dicyandiamide + Polyamine condensation reaction

Tags: experimental-chemistry, polymers, safety, amines, nitriles

I am attempting to synthesize a poly-amine polymer by condensation between dicyandiamide (also known as cyanoguanidine and dicyandiamine) and diethyltriamine. The polymer is a kind of dye fixative agent for cellulosic fabrics.

The reaction liberates ammonia. Once no more ammonia is liberated, it can be considered complete.
My lab setup is a three neck flask with stirring and a temperature between 110-160 ºC. One neck has the thermometer, the other the stirrer, and the third a tube that goes to a flask filled with acidic water, to trap the ammonia. A bit of vapor escapes through the stirrer as the seals are not perfect. The trapping flask is also exposed.

Since the reaction involves dicyandiamide and heat, I was fearful that it could also liberate some kind of toxic cyanide-like gas. In the literature there is no mention of any kind of toxic emission, however, I take safety seriously. So I wanted to know if anyone can assure me that there are no toxic cyanide-like emissions. And if they were, any advice is appreciated.

Literature:

- https://patents.google.com/patent/US5632781A/en
- https://patents.google.com/patent/US4764585A/en
- https://patents.google.com/patent/US2649354A/en

Comment: Well, accidents do happen. If you have a fume hood and sufficient experience with such reactions, you can handle that danger. If you don't, I recommend you leave the job to someone who has both.